# getting syntax error on a query even if the query is right for sure

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I'm going to deploy my ear file on glassfish but when i try to deploy the ear I get:

`2023-11-23T10:46:59.388+0100|Severe: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method 2023-11-23T10:46:59.389+0100|Severe: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method 2023-11-23T10:46:59.389+0100|Severe: Exception while preparing the app 2023-11-23T10:46:59.389+0100|Severe: Exception [EclipseLink-8025] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query`

The query is a named query and I've tested it with eclipseLink too, in a different project that do not use glassfish (without deploy it on an application server) and it works well;

I cannot figure out what's can be wrong, if the query works well using it dirctely, why it doesn't works when it is deployed on glassfish?

this is the named query

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_EXE_PROC")
@TableGenerator(name = "ExecuProcGenerator", table = "T_SEQ", pkColumnName = "SEQ_COL", valueColumnName = "SEQ_CONTATOR", pkColumnValue = "EXE_PRO_SEQUE", allocationSize = 10, initialValue = 0)
@NamedQueries({ 

        @NamedQuery(name = "ExeProc.findLastExecProcs", query = "SELECT DISTINCT (e.procedure) FROM ExeProc e WHERE e.cdExecProcs IN ( SELECT DISTINCT (e.cdExecProcs) FROM ExeProc e, ExeStep s where s.ExecProc.cdExecProcs = e.cdExecProcs AND s.stat.cdStation=:cdStation and s.oper.ceLogin=:ceLogin) and e.statusExecProc = :statusExecProc and e.procedure.status = 1 order by e.lastModifiedStepTime DESC"),

        })
public class ExeProc implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 12348979846545312L;
    
    
    public static final String FIND_LAST_EXEC_PROC = "ExeProc.findLastExecProcs";
```

I've used the query in an application java (a simple java project) and it works well;
the database is MSSQL

Comment: Please provide a [example].

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, yes I added the named query.

Comment: The error should give you more details on what it can't parse - how are you sure it is this query? If it works elsewhere, maybe check that you've got the same classes and versions in both locations - the error states EclipseLink version 2.3.2 which is quite old.

Comment: @Chris indeed you right this is the log where it works: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5 and this is where it doesn't Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461.  But if I look at maven dependency they are the same, and yes the class are copied so they are almost equals

Comment: Maven doesn't control Glassfish internals and provided jars; I'd update the jars in Glassfish if that is the version you need.

Comment: indeed I' ve checked in glassfish if there is a eclipseLink jar, but din't find it: i do not know if eclipseLink is embeded in some way in glassfish, could you tell me if there is a way to understand that? thanks anyway so much

Answer (score 0):

The problem was releted to the version of glassfish, in this version

> Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2 (build 5)

it works rights, while in this one:

> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)

Dosn't work, in other words the Open source edition is not able to do query really complex (as the one in the example);

I know may be no one else in the planet can have the issue I had, the tecnology are very old; But I do not understand why someone took two points away from me!!